# Change background color of Badge compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

The default color of the Badge is red , how to change this color in jetpack compose?
I am using `Badge` inside `BagedBox` and I have already tried `Modifier.Background`... but it is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with compose `1.1.x` with **M2** you can use the **`backgroundColor`** attribute in the `Badge` composable

```
BadgedBox(
    badge = {
        Badge(backgroundColor=Green) { Text("8") } 
    }
){
   //...
}
```

[image]

With **M3** you can use the **`containerColor`** attribute

```
androidx.compose.material3.BadgedBox(
    badge = {
        androidx.compose.material3.Badge(
            containerColor=LightGray
        )
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed the default color from red to green like this:

```
BadgedBox( badge = { Badge(containerColor = Color.Green) { 
Text(text = "8")}})
```